# Synchronous webservice for a async process in Java

Tags: java, asynchronous, jax-rs

I am providing a SOAP webservice - X that does some processing. As part of the processing it needs to invoke any other service - Y in an asynchronous fashion. That is, I send the request to service Y and would get back a 200 OK response as an acknowledgement. Later, the service Y would notify the result of the processing via another endpoint that I have exposed.

Is this possible in Java? I am aware of the CompleteableFuture class from Java 8 that aids in async computation. This is ok if I am dealing with a simple system with just one JVM. But I am not quite sure how to implement this in a distributed system comprising of multiple JVMs providing the same service X.

Any of my JVMs can receive the notification back from Y and hence I dont have a way to resume the thread operation on service X. Any thoughts / directions would be greatly helpful.

Comment: Do you have a database of some kind shared between the JVMs where you could store the association between X and Y and whether Y has finished? Perhaps even which JVM X was running on. (Does X really have to be synchronous?). Just a quick idea.

Comment: Are your X and callback endpoints on same VM? If yes, then you can use `CompleteableFuture`. If not then you need to use database or JMS type of system.

Comment: @Bjarke : Unfortunately, yes X has be synchronous and calling Y asynchronously seems to be an anti-pattern. :(  Are you suggesting to use database and constantly have X poll the status of Y from the database?

Comment: @tsolakp : With JMS too i seem to have the same problem. I can drop the results of Y into a queue after receiving notification. But I am not quite sure how to resume the operation of X after that since any of my JVMs can listen to that message from the queue. Also scalability might be a question if I designate one queue for each JVM.

Comment: You can always pass url of your endpoint to Y so that it will call back to the same VM that X is on.